# Why does inserting OLE object ClassType:="Excel.Sheet.12" cause a new worksheet to be opened?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

When inserting OLE object (embedded MS Excel File) in MS Word 2016 a new empty embedded worksheet file is opened as well.

```
Selection.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject ClassType:="Excel.Sheet.12", FileName:=DirFile4, _
  LinkToFile:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=True, IconIndex:=1, IconLabel:="Example.xlsx"
```